# how Can i show a toast between tabs?

Tags: android, timer, tabs, toast, tabactivity

when i'm switching between Tabs on a TabActivity,i just wanna ,for example,show a toast for a period of time when i'm choosing a second tab and at the end of the Timer Start the Activity .
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register an [`TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html), and in the listener put your conditions and toast.

Regarding timer before showing the Activity, I don't think you can do that.

```
tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if (tabId.equals(SECOND_TAB_STRING)) {
            // show toast
        } 
     }
});
```

Comment: i mean,i could just show it at the beginning of The activity,no need to use tabs.setOnTabChangedListener

Comment: not that i know about, but you can delay the setting off the view in the activity itself.